# it returns the value of "approved" column as "yes\0\0\0\0\0\0" instead of "yes"

Tags: c#

it returns the value of `approved` column as `"yes\0\0\0\0\0\0"` instead of `"yes"`

```
public void getapproved()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from owner_addproperties", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dtoriginaltable =ds.Tables[0];

    DataTable dtfinaltable = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dtoriginaltable.Columns)
    {
        dtfinaltable.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName);
    }

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dtfinaltable.Columns)
    {
        if (dc.ColumnName == "approved")
            dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
    }
    foreach (DataRow drow in dtoriginaltable.Rows)
    {
        if (drow["approved"].Equals("yes"))
            drow["approved"] = true;
        else
            drow["approved"] = false;

        dtfinaltable.Rows.Add(drow.ItemArray);
    }

    gvadmin_owner_view.DataSource = dtfinaltable;
    gvadmin_owner_view.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You should ask yourself how those \0 are ended in your tables first and what you can do to avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (drow["approved"].Equals("yes"))
```

to

```
if (drow["approved"].ToString().StartsWith("yes"))
```